# How to remove a widget in just one layer in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. In `Dashboard > Widget` I assigned two widget on `default layer` and I created a `Blog layer` with rule `url("~/blog*")`. What I want is to disable one of the widgets in this `blog layer` only. How Can I achieve this?

Comment: you can create new layer with rule (not url("~/blog*")), and add this widget to it.

Comment: Very nice, thanks mate